# Jquery get window.location.search tag in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say i have this address: http://****/test.php?alfa=1&beta=2

I know that i can get ?alfa=1&beta=2 using the search tag in window location.... but is there any way to split the result into 2 strings, in this case, first would be ?alfa=1 and the second one &beta=2 (or just beta=2) using JQuery?

Comment: `var parameters = url.split("?")[1].split("&");` then that would set parameter[0] = "alfa=1"....parameter[1] = "beta=2"

Comment: Thank you..i knew there was a split tag in java...but i did not think that it might also be one in jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Split method,

sample-
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var n = str.split(" ");

will give you array 
How,are,you,doing,today?.

for your problem you can spit text using '?' keyword first and next by '&' key...

Comment: A very good answer indeed..thank you kind sir :) i will mark this as the final answer

Answer (score 3):

```
// Read a page's GET URL variables and return them as an associative array.
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Not my work. Found it [here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.ie/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html) First hit on Google.

Comment: yea..it looks good (from the code point of view) but it is just too complicated for what i need

Comment: take what you need from it. 


window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&')[0] will give you alfa, 


window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&')[1] will give you beta

Answer (score 0):

there is a plugin jQuery BBQ: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

You can use the following function, but it returns an object and not an array

```
var params = $.deparam.querystring();
console.log(params);

Object {alfa: "1", beta: "2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

URL: //somesite.com/?v1=1&v2=2&v3=3

```
$(function () {
  var in_url = [];
  var in_url_str = window.location.search.replace('?','').split('&');
  $.each(in_url_str,function (kay,val) {
    var v = val.split('=');
    in_url[v[0]]=v[1];
  });
  console.log(in_url);
});
```

in console

```
[v1: "1", v2: "2", v3: "3"]
v1:"1"
v2:"2"
v3:"3"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let params = [];
let query = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.replace('?','')).split('&');
query.map((row)=>{
    let r = row.split("=");
    params[r[0]] = r[1];
})
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Answer (score -1):

To get a Json object with keys.

```
JSON.parse('{' + window.location.search.slice(1).split('&').map(x => { y = x.split('='); return '"' + y[0] + '":' + y[1]}).join(',')  + '}')
```